# QGIS Reproject a set of points in CSV to another CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, csv

I have a few points collected in Google Earth, and now stored in a CSV file:

```
lat long
47.17347661 7.584905937
47.17347661 7.584905937
47.17756055 7.578652797
47.17756055 7.578652797
47.18636237 7.57629175
```

and I would like to reproject them to LV95 LN02.
I have tried several times to both use "Export > Save Features As > CRS: LV95" or with the function "Processing > Toolbox > Reproject Layer".. but either I get errors or the projection does not work... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Load the `csv` as a `Delimited Text`
   [image]
2. As mentioned in the comments by J.R. - Do some visual checks if the data is where it should be - if they are off check the `CRS` or if `Lat`/`Lng` are swapped etc.
3. Export the data (Right Click the new layer --> Export --> Save Features as)
   [image]
4. In the properties set your CRS to `EPSG:2056` (or any other CRS you want to export to) change the Format to `CSV` (or any other format). If it is `CSV` set the `GEOMETRY` property to `AS_XY` and the `SEPERATOR` to your choice.
   [image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: You may add a step between 1 and 2 to check that the import is "right" (right CRS, no Lat/Lon inversion, right field type, ...)

Comment: good point. some visual check should be done!

Comment: thanks a lot, very. helpufl!!!! :-)

Comment: opsss......@Bernd Loigge, I have followed exactly your procedure, but I got an error once I was exporting the new csv file (it did not allow me to create the csv file)....

```Export to vector file failed.
Error: Feature write errors:
Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed to create ./reprojected_coordinates.csv:
Read-only file system)
Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed to create ./reprojected_coordinates.csv:
Read-only file system)
Only 0 of 5 features written.
Storing metadata for the specified uri is not supported```

Comment: Well, it looks like it is a ```Read-only file system``` - so you don't have the rights to export the CSV (at least not to the path you specified)